# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on code injection (armv7 asm)

Tags: assembly, armv7, thumb

I have no idea why the following code hits a `BAD_INSTRUCTION` error, anyone?

```
mov    r4, r0
movw   r0, #0xc70   ; injected code start here
movt   r0, #0x8bb3
movw   r3, #0x576
ldr    r1, [r7]
movs   r5, #0x1a
add    r5, pc       ; next instruction will jump over 9 instructions
bx     r5           ; injected code end here
ldr    r1, [r0]
ldr    r0, [r2]
blx    0x26e11c
movw   r1, #0x6442
movt   r1, #0x18
add    r1, pc
ldr    r1, [r1]
blx    0x26e11c
mov    r3, r1
movw   r1, #0x66a4  ; r1 has not been loaded
movt   r1, #0x15    ; with new value. Why?
mov    r2, r0
add    r1, pc       ; This instruction isn't getting called
mov    r0, r4       ; EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION here
blx    __sprintf
```

Comment: Why not single-step through the code in your debugger and see what's actually going on ?

Comment: @PaulR I did, as you can see my comment on each instruction. After `bx r5`, everything looks ok to me. But next 2 movw & movt set nothing to r1, and after that the process felt to `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

Comment: Are you sure about the value `0x1a`?  If you were off by +/- 1byte, I could see the debugger being confused about where you are in the code (so it *looks* like you are tracing over the code you expect), but since you wouldn't be executing the instructions you think you are... Just a thought.

Comment: what processor/core is this?  you are using bx to switch from thumb to arm mode.  does your processor support arm mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the 26 byte offset (i.e. no multiple of 4-byte ARM instructions) and the immediate generation being flag-setting (`movs r5, #0x1a`), I sense this is Thumb code. However, `bx r5` is an interworking branch, and since bit 0 of r5 isn't being set, it's going to interwork to ARM state into the middle of some Thumb instructions and get very unhappy. Since I believe `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` is iOS's reporting of an undefined instruction exception, that all looks to add up.

If you're in Thumb state and want to stay in Thumb state, either use a non-interworking branch (i.e. `mov pc, r5`), or ensure bit 0 of the `bx` target is set (i.e. make the offset 0x1b).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I forgot to set bit 0 of the destination address in r5.